# Creating file with QB64

Tags: file-io, basic

With the following

```
DIM a AS INTEGER
a = 10
OPEN "myFile" FOR BINARY AS #1
PUT #1, 1, a
CLOSE #1
```

I get a file (myFile) with two bytes (using QB64). The first byte is indeed `0A`, but there is a second byte `00`.

How can I create a file with just one byte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DIM a AS _UNSIGNED _BYTE
a = 10
OPEN "myFile" FOR BINARY AS #1
PUT #1, 1, a
CLOSE #1
```

It seems like `INTEGER` is 2 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Snip to write a byte to file:

```
DIM B AS STRING * 1
x = 10
B = CHR$(x)
OPEN "myfile" FOR BINARY AS #1
PUT #1, 1, B
CLOSE #1
```